# Package natbib Warning: Citation `xy' on page 8 undefined on input line xy

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I know this problem has been covered in other questions, but I can't find my mistake. Here comes my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}      

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{geometry}                       
\usepackage{graphicx}   
                        
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}        

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{...}
\author{...}
\date{22.02.2021}                       

\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
\cite{triton}
...
\medskip
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{cit}
\end{document}
```

and my cit.bib file:

```
@report{Morrison1974,
   abstract = {This paper reviews the physical nature of the satellites of the planets, excluding the Moon but including the rings of Saturn. Emphasis is placed on the best studied objects: Titan, Phobos and Deimos, the four Galilean satellites (Io, Europa, Ganymede, and Callisto), and the rings of Saturn.},
   author = {David Morrison and Dale P Cruikshank},
   title = {PHYSICAL PROPERTIES OF THE NATURAL SATELLITES*},
   year = {1974}}
@report{triton,
   abstract = {Thermal continuum and spectral line observations of Triton were performed in the 870 micron window in October 2016 using the Atacama Large Millime-ter/Submillimeter Array (ALMA). We find an average brightness temperature of 31.9±2.5 K for the surface, very similar to that found for Pluto in 2015 with the same ALMA spectral setup. We also detect emission from the CO(3-2) and HCN(4-3) rotation transitions, originating in Triton's atmosphere. The CO mole fraction ranges from 30-230 ppm, depending on the assumed surface pressure.},
   author = {Mark Gurwell and Emmanuel Lellouch and Bryan J Butler and Raphael Moreno and Arielle Moullet and Darrell F Strobel},
   title = {The Atmosphere of Triton Observed With ALMA}}
```

help is well appreciated, was sitting on this for the whole day now :/

Comment: You have two `\bibliographystyle`s in your document (`\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` in the preamble after you load `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` in the document body before `\bibliography`), but a document may only contain one `\bibliographystyle` command. Delete one of the two `\bibliographystyle`s, so that you only have one in your entire document.

Comment: thank you @moewe! I did delete the second one, still get no listed Bibliography at the end of the document and only question marks in my citations....